# how to make spring REST api consumer

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am new to ``` spring``REST ``` api design. Somehow I have created a api (producer). Now I want to consume this same `API`. I have never consumed API before. How can I do so ? I have tried using `HttpURLConnection` but couldn't do it. Below is my code for producer api. Now I want to call this API using java code.

**Rest Api (producer)**

```
@PostMapping(value="register")
    public ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler> doRegister(@RequestPart String json,@RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile file)  throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {    
        try {

            String imgPath = env.getProperty("image_path");

            String outputDir = imgPath; 

            RegEntity reg = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, RegEntity.class);

            String  result = validateInsertRegBean(reg);
            if(!result.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                return new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed,result),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            }
            String imagePath=null;
            System.out.println("=================================");
            if(file!=null && !file.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("file NOT nOT NOT EmpTY");
            String username=reg.getUsername();
            File userFile = new File(outputDir+username);
            if(!userFile.exists()) {
                userFile.mkdir();
            }

            try {
                file.transferTo(new File(outputDir+username+File.separator+ file.getOriginalFilename()));
                System.out.println("***************   "+file.getOriginalFilename());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed,"image unable to upload"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }


            File ff[] = userFile.listFiles();
            for(File f:ff) {
                if(f.getName().contains("thumbnail"))
                    f.delete();
            }


            Thumbnails.of(new File(outputDir+username+File.separator).listFiles())
            .size(100, 100)
            .outputFormat("jpg")
            .toFiles(Rename.SUFFIX_HYPHEN_THUMBNAIL);

            imagePath=outputDir+username+File.separator+file.getOriginalFilename();

            }
            Date dt = new Date();
            long lngDt = dt.getTime();
            Ofuser ofuser = new Ofuser();
            ofuser.setBlockedNum(null);
            ofuser.setEmail(reg.getEmail());
            ofuser.setEncryptedPassword(reg.getEncryptedPassword());
            ofuser.setName(reg.getName());
            ofuser.setStatus(reg.getStatus());
            ofuser.setUsername(reg.getUsername());
            ofuser.setVcardResize(null);
            ofuser.setImage(null);
            ofuser.setPlainPassword(null);
            ofuser.setCreationDate(lngDt+"");
            ofuser.setModificationDate(lngDt+"");
            ofuser.setImagePath(imagePath);
            Ofuser tempuser = ofuserService.save(ofuser);
            IdMaster idMaster0 = new IdMaster();
            idMaster0.setUsername(tempuser.getUsername());
            idMaster0.setUserId(lngDt+"");
            IdMaster tempidMaster = idMasterService.save(idMaster0);
            if(tempuser!=null && tempidMaster!=null) {
                System.out.println("################## "+tempuser.getUsername());
                return new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(
                        new SuccessResponseBean(HttpStatus.OK, ResponseStatusEnum.SUCCESSFUL, ApplicationResponse.SUCCESSFUL),
                        HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            else {
                return new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(
                        new SuccessResponseBean(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed),
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed,"something went wrong!!"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        }
    }
```

**postman screenshot**

[image]

On postman its working fine. Now I want to consume this very api programatically.  how can I do this.
Basically I need to call this method using some code:

```
 @PostMapping(value="register")
        public ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler> doRegister(@RequestPart String json,@RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile file){}
```

don't have much experience in doing so..please guide.

============================================================================

Ok, after much digging in google I made following code but still not able to call rest api. My code:

```
package com.google.reg.utils;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8012/register");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW charset=utf-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            JSONObject jsonObject = buidJsonObject();
            setPostRequestContent(conn, jsonObject);
            conn.connect();
            System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
            if(conn.getResponseCode()==200){
                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                System.out.println(stringBuilder+" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" );
                jsonObject=new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());    
            }
            else{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                System.out.println(stringBuilder+" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" );
                System.out.println("ERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERROR"+conn.getResponseCode());
            }

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static  JSONObject buidJsonObject() throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("username", "129898912");
        jsonObject.accumulate("encryptedPassword", "encpass");
        jsonObject.accumulate("name",  "fish");
        jsonObject.accumulate("email",  "fish@fish.com");
        jsonObject.accumulate("status",  "active");


        return jsonObject;
    }

    private static void setPostRequestContent(HttpURLConnection conn, 
            JSONObject jsonObject) throws IOException {

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

but still no success. Below is the error I get in console:

```
400
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Wed Sep 26 12:28:17 UTC 2018</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).</div><div>Required request part &#39;json&#39; is not present</div></body></html>
 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
ERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERROR400
```

Comment: if you want to use in JSP page you can use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, you can use RestTemplate which is again a spring library. 
Please refer [rest template](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)

This is actually one client, but there are more. Its up to you do decide which one you should use and which suites best to you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Damith said, rest template is a good library, and it's embedded on the springboot dependency tree. But also there are some others library, such as [OkHttp](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp) or [JAX-RX](https://www.baeldung.com/jax-rs-reactive-client) which can help you. My favorite one is OkHttp3, Good Luck.